# How to make x-axis start from 0 in chart.js graphs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, chart.js

I am using chart.js library and I am having a issue. I want the years axis to start from 0.  Right now its starting from the negative value(-50 in my case).

**Currently its coming like this-**
[image]

**What I want-**
[image]

**What I am trying-**

```js
var config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Year 0", "Year 1", "Year 2", "Year 3", "Year 4", "Year 5", "Year 6"],
    datasets: [{


      type: 'line',
      label: 'Accumulative Flow',
      data: [0, -50, 20, 30, 40, 50],
      borderColor: 'red',
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0,
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      xAxes: [{
        barPercentage: 0.4
      }]
    }, {
      type: 'bar',
      label: 'Benifit(One time)',
      backgroundColor: "#005998",
      data: [40, 50, 60, 80, 50, 60],
    }, ]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Custom Chart Title'
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        time: {
          displayFormats: {
            quarter: ' YYYY'
          }
        },

        beginAtZero: true,
        barPercentage: 0.3,
        id: 'x-axis-label',
        position: 'bottom',
        scaleStartValue: 20,
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
      }],
      yAxes: [{

        id: 'y-axis-label',
        ticks: {
          max: 300,
          min: -50,
          stepSize: 50,
        },
        position: 'left',
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
      }]
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'right'
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scaleBeginAtZero: true


  }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```css
.GraphContain {
  max-height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<div class="GraphContain">
  <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

> Is there any parameter to do this ?

Thanks In advance!

Comment: The graph you want is not ideal because the line chart overlaps the labels. Try the https://jsfiddle.net/dj67o0vk/

Comment: Overlapping will not be a problem . i just want the x-axis it to start from 0. @DroidNoob

Comment: I think I have an easier solution than my answer below but didn't know if this question was already dead.

Comment: @jordanwillisThis question is still alive ;)

Comment: Let me attempt a 3rd option tomorrow of an idea i had.  I assumed​ you saw my answer already?

Comment: Yes I saw your answer its nice. But can I also see your 3rd option? I think this will help a lot of people too having  the similar problem ;)

Comment: Check out my updated answer!

Comment: Its just perfect ;) Thanks a lot @jordanwillis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reading thru the core scale source, I was able to come up with a way to configure your chart to get pretty dang close to your desired behavior.

It requires that we manually set gridline colors as well as manipulate the internal scale instance `ticks` array (which is used by the scale draw method to paint on the canvas).

First, in order to hide some gridlines but show others, I used the `gridLines.color` property and passed in an array of colors where the first index color is the default gridline color and all others are white (the first index is used to color the "zero" gridline).  Note, since we are later going to manipulate the internal scale `ticks` array, you must add an extra index to the color array with a color of white.  Here is an example of what I mean.

```
gridLines: {
    // since we only want to show the "zero line" gridline (chart.js
    // uses the color of the first index to paint this line), we
    // set the first index to the default color and all others to white
    // note, later we add a "dummy" tick (explained later) so the length
    // of this array has to be 1 greater than the number of gridlines you
    // want displayed
    color: [
      "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)", // this is for the zero line
      "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
      "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
      "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
      "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
      "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
      "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
      "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
      "rgb(255, 255, 255)",],
  }
}
```

Next, we use the [`afterTickToLabelConversion` scale callback configuration property](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-common-configuration) to manipulate the internal scale `ticks` array to force the gridlines to display like you want.  Here is the implementation that works for your use case.

```
// we will use this callback to manipulate the ticks array
// before they are drawn on the canvas
afterTickToLabelConversion: function(scaleInstance) {
  // the top gridline (which is at index 0) is always shown 
  // so to overcome this we add a "dummy" tick at index 0
  scaleInstance.ticks.unshift(null);

  // we have to do the same this to this tick array as well
  // because it uses the values in this array to map to the data
  scaleInstance.ticksAsNumbers.unshift(null);

  // since we have added an extra tick, we need to move the 
  // zero line index to point to the new index of 0
  scaleInstance.zeroLineIndex++
}
```

So putting it all together you end up with a chart that looks like this.

[image: chart example]

Check out this [codepen](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/XMYVNE) for a working example (note, I left the other attempts to solve this...so see option 3 at the bottom).